# iframe width is too large

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make an iframe that stretches to the full width and height of the page but when using "width:100%" I get a too large iframe as shown in the image.

[image]

This is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <style>
  </style>
  <body>

    <h2>Text example to show that the width is too large and the content is out of it</h2>
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <iframe src="index.php" style="width:100%;height:1500px;overflow:hidden; border:none;"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add a question to your post

Comment: The question is how to fix that problem of 100% width taking more width than the screen size. Here on he code snippet it seems like it works great but for some reason when I place it on my main.php file (exactly the same code as here) what I've showed in the image happens. I've tried a different src of the iframe that I saw on w3school that did work good but same problem of 100% width being larger then the screen size

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the container element (body, main, content, whatever) has a left and right padding. Use the browser tools to inspect alle lements that could be responsible for that. If you find it, try to remove that padding. If you can't for some reason, use `width: 100vw` for the iframe and apply a **negative**  `margin-left` to it that has the same value (but negative)  as the left-padding of the container element.

So, for example, if there is a `padding-left: 30px` on the `body`, apply `margin-left: -30px` (and `width: 100vw`) to that iframe.